# Why does running this AngularJS code locally work, but not on IIS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-provider

I have a settings provider that runs fine on localhost, but doesn't work on IIS. The error from AngularJS is:

```
[$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: appLevelProvider
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/unpr?p0=appLevelProvider
    at https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:234:12
    at https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:4957:19
    at getService (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:5112:32)
    at injectionArgs (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:5137:58)
    at Object.instantiate (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:5183:18)
    at provider (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:4994:36)
    at Object.provider (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:4986:16)
    at runInvokeQueue (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:5058:35)
    at https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:5067:11
    at forEach (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:570:20)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20appLevelProvider%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.3%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3DappLevelProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A234%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A4957%3A19%0A%20%20%20%20at%20getService%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A5112%3A32)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20injectionArgs%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A5137%3A58)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.instantiate%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A5183%3A18)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20provider%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A4994%3A36)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.provider%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A4986%3A16)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20runInvokeQueue%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A5058%3A35)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A5067%3A11%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A570%3A20)
    at https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:234:12
    at https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:4957:19
    at getService (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:5112:32)
    at injectionArgs (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:5137:58)
    at Object.instantiate (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:5183:18)
    at provider (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:4994:36)
    at Object.provider (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:4986:16)
    at runInvokeQueue (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:5058:35)
    at https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:5067:11
    at forEach (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:570:20)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20Unknown%20provider%3A%20appLevelProvider%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.3%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3DappLevelProvider%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A234%3A12%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A4957%3A19%0A%20%20%20%20at%20getService%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A5112%3A32)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20injectionArgs%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A5137%3A58)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.instantiate%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A5183%3A18)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20provider%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A4994%3A36)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.provider%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A4986%3A16)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20runInvokeQueue%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A5058%3A35)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A5067%3A11%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(https%3A%2F%2Fengdeviis.nscorp.com%2FTRIMS_WebAPI%2Fsrc%2FBuild%2Fvendor.bundle.js%3A570%3A20)
    at https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:234:12
    at https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:5088:15
    at forEach (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:570:20)
    at loadModules (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:5048:5)
    at createInjector (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:4970:19)
    at doBootstrap (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:2077:20)
    at bootstrap (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:2098:12)
    at angularInit (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:1983:5)
    at https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:33508:5
    at HTMLDocument.trigger (https://engdeviis.nscorp.com/TRIMS_WebAPI/src/Build/vendor.bundle.js:3603:5)
```

Here is the code in settingsservice.js:

```
/// <reference path="../libraries/angular.js" />
/// <reference path="../libraries/extensionmethods.js" />

angular.module('app').
provider('settings', ['appLevelProvider','versionProvider', function (appLevelProvider, versionProvider) {
    var appLev = appLevelProvider.$get();
    var ver = versionProvider.$get();
    return {
        $get: function () {
            (Code omitted)
        }
    }
}]);
```

I've stepped through the debugger locally and on the server and when running locally appLevelProvider is available for cache.hasOwnProperty() to return true. However, on the server, appLevelProvider is not there. The code is not being minified.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: "_What am I missing?_" an `appLevelProvider`. Show your scripts

Comment: I supplied the relevant source.

Comment: Ignoring your snark, you clearly missed the fact that it runs fine locally, but not on IIS using the exact same code.